# Kendo Grid, datatable bind: System.ArgumentException: Property with specified name: ID cannot be found on type: System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, editablegrid

To my view I send Model where one property is DataTable(called Data), which I bind to Kendo Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Data)
   .Name("MyGrid")
   .Columns(c =>
   {
       if (Model.Data != null)
       {
           int index = 0;
           foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Data.Columns)
           {
               var col = c.Bound(column.ColumnName).Width("300px").EditorTemplateName("String");
               if (index < 2)
               {
                   col.Locked(true).Lockable(false);
               }
               index++;
           }
       }
   })
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.Row[0]);
        if (Model.Data != null)
        {
            model.Id(Model.Data.Columns[0].ColumnName);
            int index = 0;
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Data.Columns)
            {
                var field = model.Field(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
                 if (index < 2)
               {
                   field.Editable(false);
               }
               index++;
            }
        }
    })
    .PageSize(20)
.Create(update => update.Action("Create", "Home"))
.Update(up => up.Action("UpdateRow", "Home"))
)  
.Editable(editable => editable
    .Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)
    )
    .Selectable(selectable =>
    {
        selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single);
        selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Row);
    })
.Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(500))
.Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
.Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:100%" })
.Pageable()
.Navigatable()
.Sortable()
.Groupable(g => g.ShowFooter(true))
    )
```

The problem is with line field.Editable(false) - when I try to set true it works. It says that I do not have ID value in my DataRowView - I am pretty sure my DataTable have column called ID, I checked it like 100+times.
Exact Error:

> Property with specified name: ID cannot be found on type:
>   System.Data.DataRowView Parameter name: propertyName
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Property with specified
>   name: ID cannot be found on type: System.Data.DataRowView Parameter
>   name: propertyName

Comment: Also very important is to activate autosync: 
<script>
        kendo.data.DataSource.prototype.options.autoSync = true; // very important
    </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have baypass the problem. 
I have used

```
.Events(events =>
    {
        events.Edit("edit_handler");
    })
```

where my function looks:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function edit_handler(e) {
            var grid = $('#MyGrid').data('kendoGrid');
            var fieldName = grid.columns[e.container.index()].field;
            var columnsToEdit = document.getElementById('EditableColumns').textContent;
            var arrayOfColumns = columnsToEdit.split(",");
            if (arrayOfColumns.indexOf(fieldName.toUpperCase()) < 0) {
                $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").closeCell(e.container);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Where "EditableColumns" label contains all columns names which should be editable.